# How to convert binary JSON in Swift with SwiftyJSON?

Tags: json, swift, websocket, socket.io, swifty-json

When using Alamofire to retrieve a JSON that contains strings as well as a binary, the conversion to `JSON` works perfectly fine:

```
Alamofire.request(path, method: .get, parameters: parameters)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    print("GET request to '" + path + "' has been successful.")
                    if let value = response.result.value {
                        let json = JSON(value)
                        onCompletion(json as JSON, nil)
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    onCompletion(nil, error as NSError?)
                }
        }
```

Now I have WebSockets via [socket.io-client-swift](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) implemented and I want to do the same thing, namely receiving a JSON that contains strings as well as a binary. Sending works fine, but unfortunately not receiving messages from the server. However, I think that the problem is with the conversion from an `NSArray` to `JSON`, because when printing the array, the result is like this:

```
(
        {
        bin = <ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 [....] 51494b40 05251494 01ffd9>;
        userId = 582d6f52b49e931d3fb6d56a;
        bla = 1221321424214124214;
        type = binary;
    }
)
```

When converting this `NSArray` to JSON via SwiftyJSON, I get `unknown`.

```
SocketIO.sharedInstance.onMessage({ data, ack in
            print(data) // prints the array above
            let json = JSON(data[0])
            print(json) // unknown
            // do more stuff
        })
```

If I send text instead of `bin`, everything works just fine. I also tried to use the `JSON(data: data[0])` initializer, but this does not work due to a wrong type.

What also seems strange for me is when I print the incoming message with the following statement:

```
socket.on("message") {( dataArray, ack) -> Void in
            print("Incoming: ", dataArray);
}
```

I get the following output, which seems that a nested array has been transmitted, and not an array that has an object as its first element:

```
Incoming:  [["userId": 582d6f52b49e931d3fb6d56a, "bla": 1221321424214124214, "type": binary, "bin": 205083 bytes]]
```

What could be the problem here?

**EDIT:**

I noticed that the transferred binary differs when retrieving messages via REST and Socket.io. To be specific, on the iOS client, I receive the following when using REST:

```
bin =             {
                data =                 (
                    255,
                    216,
                    255,
                    224,
                    0,
                    [.....],
                    161,
                    163,
                    68,
                    207,
                    255,
                    217
                );
                type = Buffer;
            };
```

When using Socket.io, I receive it like this:

```
bin = <ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 01000048 [......]>;
```

Although the JSON looks the same when logging the message right before transmitting it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently [socket.io-client-swift](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) is not able to handle Buffers. I solved this issue by converting the buffer to an `Uint8Array` and then to an normal array, before sending it via websockets:

```
Array.from(new Uint8Array(stored.bin.buffer))
```